# how to convert hashMap to Json file

Tags: java, gwt

I am leaning Java.

I have to transfer a Hashmap to Server using rpc.

HashMap

```
Map<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
testMap .put("1", "abc");
testMap .put("2", "ezc");
testMap .put("3", "afc");
testMap .put("4", "cvc");
..
```

how to do that.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213734/using-gson-library-in-gwt-client-code

Comment: I don't need an answer to tell you to use Gson.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this link if its helps..

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
testMap .put("1", "abc"); 
testMap .put("2", "ezc"); 
testMap .put("3", "afc"); 
testMap .put("4", "cvc"); 

      mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), testMap);
```

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at [Jackson JSON processor](http://jackson.codehaus.org). In particular the code will look something like:

```
Map map = your map
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
```

If you want pretty JSON (multiple lines) for debugging, then use:

```
String json = mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter().writeValueAsString(map);
```

Answer (score 4):

you can also try `GSON` library. It is fast and easy to use.
The Below wrapper class will make your job even more easy

```
public class ConvertJsonToObject {

    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    public static final <T> T getFromJSON(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
        return gson.fromJson(json, clazz);
    }

    public static final <T> String toJSON(T clazz) {
        return gson.toJson(clazz);
    }
}
```

All you need to do is

```
Map<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
testMap .put("1", "abc");
testMap .put("2", "ezc");
testMap .put("3", "afc");
testMap .put("4", "cvc");
String json = ConvertJsonToObject.toJSON(testMap);
```

and you can easily get your `original Object` back on the `other side`

```
Map<String, String> newTestMap = ConvertJsonToObject.getFromJSON(json,Map.class);
```

Comment: Why are your static methods final?

Comment: :) @SteveKuo i Usually write final if i dont expect the class to be extended in future..got used to it. my bad

Answer (score 2):

I don't catch : HashMap is Serializable so should be able to be used between client and server?