# Compilation error: No source code is available for type com.google.gson.Gson

Tags: java, json, gwt, gson

I'm trying to parse a json string on client side using **Gson** but while installing project getting an error:

```
 No source code is available for type com.google.gson.Gson; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

I have added `<inherits name='com.google.gson.Gson' />` on my gwt.xml.
I'm using GWT 2.8.1 can we use Gson on client side ?
[this][1]

[using Gson library in GWT client code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213734/using-gson-library-in-gwt-client-code) used older version of GWT and my question is also related to error of Gson module .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using Gson library in GWT client code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213734/using-gson-library-in-gwt-client-code)

Comment: The error is pretty self-descriptive: client-scope GWT uses libraries source code to compile it to JavaScript. Also, GWT can only use a very limited set of JDK features, whilst Gson is built some advanced of them, therefore you *cannot* use Gson at the client side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gson is not GWT compatible. You should use a GWT compatible library like [gwt-jackson](https://github.com/nmorel/gwt-jackson).

Alternatively, if your models are simple you can use a technique called JsInterop DTOs. And use the browser native `JSON.parse` function directly. This technique is based in [JsInterop](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJsInterop.html) and some limitation explained [here](https://github.com/intendia-oss/autorest/wiki/JsInterop-DTO-strategy). Example:

```
@JsType(isNative = true, namespace = JsPackage.GLOBAL, name = "Object") 
class SearchResult {
    public String display_name; //ex: "Málaga, Provincia de Málaga, Andalusia, Spain"
    public String lat, lon; //ex: lat: "36.7210805", lon: "-4.4210409"
    public double importance; //ex: 0.73359836669253
}
```

And then call native parse (need to import elemental2-core library):

```
Object jsonObj = elemental2.core.Global.JSON.parse(jsonStr);
SearchResult result = jsinterop.base.Js.cast(jsonObj);
```

Comment: This chat room is a pretty good place if you are not sure what is the best option for your specific use case https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt/. GWT has too many options and it is super frequently to get confused, so go to the chat and discuss your case!

Comment: Thanks @Ignacio Baca ,JSON.parse() is working in my case,actually i won't need to use JsInterop. to use object i have used               
 public static native String getObject(String jsVar)/*-{
                 return  eval('$wnd.' + jsVar);
                 }-*/;

Comment: That's the old way, ;) JsInterop is the new strategy, much clean and future proof! Strongly recommended 