# How to use XMLHttpRequest in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-2.8, gwt-jsinterop, gwt-elemental

XMLHttpRequest is an alternative for HTTP calls from GWT client side and allows the control over all aspects of requests/responses. But how to use it?
javadoc address: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/xhr/client/class-use/XMLHttpRequest.html

Comment: which version of gwt do you use? is it a maven project?

Comment: Elemental2 is the way to go :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You haven't mentioned what GWT version you use, so I assume the latest one. It means 2.8.2 or newer.

## Elemental2 is the way to go

As it is mentioned in comments above, `Elemental2` is the right way. I will explain it a bit.

If you think about future-proof implementation (being aware of `GWT3`/`J2CL` new approach), please do not use legacy GWT stuff. It means please use `elemental2.dom.XMLHttpRequest` instead of `com.google.gwt.xhr.client.XMLHttpRequest` (the one mentioned by you). Please do not use `gwt-user` dependency if possible, as it will be deprecated (if it is not already).

The `Elemental2` is an opensource project available here: https://github.com/google/elemental2. It is kind of a base library for the "new GWT". For easier migration of existing GWT2.x projects to GWT3.x, a part of the "old" `gwt-user` is currently being ported to the new approach using `JsInterop` technique and mentioned `Elemental2`. So definitely `Elemental2` is the way to go.

## Elemental2 and JsInterop in general

The specification is not yet that rich if about the new JsInterop approach, but at the moment you will find some introduction at least: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJsInterop.html

## Examples

Please find an example for `XMLHttpRequest` in this article:
http://www.g-widgets.com/2016/09/09/gwt-http-requests-alternatives/

If you look for examples, also a good way is to search this on the Github site this way: https://github.com/search?q=elemental2.dom.XMLHttpRequest&type=Code.

*(To use Github search you need to be logged in, in other case you will see "Whoa there! You have triggered an abuse blah blah..." )*

One of the results will lead you to the very interesting project (you have the preview of the future `GWT` now):
https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt-http. It is
a future-proof port of the legacy `com.google.gwt.http.HTTP` GWT module. It will help to migrate GWT2.x projects to GWT3.x.

When you look to the test package, you will find some examples: https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt-http/tree/master/src/test/java/org/gwtproject/http/client .
So this is finally **the answer to your question**: "how to use it?" :-)

**An additional examples** source for `XMLHttpRequest` (using `Elemental2`) from Gist: https://gist.github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=elemental2.dom.XMLHttpRequest. This is probably even better for start, as they are short and clear.

## What Elemental2 is?

The `Elemental2` gives you a type checked access to native browser's API. So if you are familiar with browser's API, you should be able to implement your stuff, even based on some native JavaScript example. Please think about the new GWT like about type safe JavaScript (in addition very performant and well optimized). With `JsInterop` you create bindings, so it is something similar to bindings for TypeScript. So in fact you have a possibility to deal directly with browser's API, without anything GWT specific.

## Libraries? More examples...?

Dealing with `XMLHttpRequest` is a bit low level.

You have also a possibility to use the library. One of Github search results will lead you to this repository: https://github.com/ibaca/autorest-streaming-example which is an example for interesting REST library: https://github.com/intendia-oss/autorest. A modern and reactive one, works with Observables, RxJava and so on.
This library uses `JsInterop` and is also migrated to `Elemental2` what makes it `GWT3`/`J2CL` ready, please see the change: https://github.com/intendia-oss/autorest/commit/58516802cd42134544e6e3787207b5431fae94b5 .

With the Github search query I provided you, now you are able to find even more code examples for `XMLHttpRequest`. So please just have a look and find the best one for your needs.

An alternative approach would be to use a framework, for instance Errai from RedHat: http://erraiframework.org/. It helps you to deal with many problems at a different abstraction level.

I think now you have some references to study.

## On the other hand it's 2018, so why not the Fetch API?

When think about the modern web application, I would rather think about the `Fetch API` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`. All modern browsers now implement the `fetch()` function natively. Isn't it the best way for solving your issue then?
The `fetch()` is a Promise-based mechanism that allows you to make network requests similar to `XMLHttpRequest`. Promises and Fetch are handled by Elemental2. Then you can use it from your Java code more or less in similar way like in Mozilla's examples.

Read more about the `Fetch API` here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch
- https://codepen.io/aderaaij/post/fetching-data-with-fetch
- https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/

What more, this is nothing new as you see.
If about the older browsers a `polyfill` will emulate the missing function: https://github.com/github/fetch.

If about examples, I don't see that much on Github:
https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=elemental2.dom.DomGlobal+fetch&type=Code, but at least something.

The `Fetch API` seems to be the most current solution to the problem.

Please find a very simple fetch() example using Elemental2.

The imports section:

```
import static elemental2.dom.DomGlobal.fetch;
import static elemental2.dom.DomGlobal.console;
import elemental2.dom.Response;
```

Then use in your code:

```
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?gender=female&results=1")
            .then(Response::json)
            .then(data -> {
                console.log(Global.JSON.stringify(data));
                return null;
            }).
            catch_(error -> {
                console.log(error);
                return null;
            });
```

As a result you should be able to see something like this:

```
{"results":[{"gender":"female","name":{"title":"mrs","first":"caroline","last":"coleman"},"location":{"street":"3703 new road","city":"swansea","state":"leicestershire","postcode":"ZH67 0YS","coordinates":{"latitude":"14.7870","longitude":"-107.8990"},"timezone":{"offset":"-6:00","description":"Central Time (US & Canada), Mexico City"}},"email":"caroline.coleman@example.com","login":{"uuid":"25357d90-cce4-4fe6-a3db-8ab77c0272ba","username":"smallpeacock582","password":"citizen","salt":"VX3s05Ah","md5":"84649cce1db8c6f2cbe33098221aa570","sha1":"005abf7d2ca0ff5b1a0bfd6dcee6d4860ef6e75d","sha256":"caadff0a16e27b0d9893aea483aedc7cf7c4707096c33a58acf44336bb2b54be"},"dob":{"date":"1978-03-14T15:47:16Z","age":40},"registered":{"date":"2013-08-10T19:09:41Z","age":5},"phone":"015396 74385","cell":"0726-723-103","id":{"name":"NINO","value":"JA 32 24 22 P"},"picture":{"large":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/45.jpg","medium":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/45.jpg","thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/45.jpg"},"nat":"GB"}],"info":{"seed":"98f4f4a344470fbd","results":1,"page":1,"version":"1.2"}}
```

You can further convert the result to Java object using a technique called JsInterop DTOs. If you are interested, please find some information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50565283/5394086 .

## Not recommended approach

If you sadly prefer to use the old GWT, so <= 2.7, then I think you can search for some examples on Github using similar search query, but for this legacy com.google.gwt.xhr.client.XMLHttpRequest. I this case I would also suggest you to not do stuff so low level, but use a library like https://github.com/reinert/requestor (which is unfortunately discontinued and development has stopped on GWT 2.7, but for this GWT version it is probably the best choice). But again please do not go this way and use GWT >= 2.8.2 with `Elemental2`/`JsInterop` approach instead.

Comment: I would like to add https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-rest as a simple wrapper for elemental2 XmlHttpRequest, also the GWT XmlHttpRequest has already been ported for those who are seeking easy migration the ported lib can be found here https://github.com/rjeeb/gwt-xhr

Comment: Just one thing: the fetch API is implemented in Edge starting with v14. Older versions of Egde or all versions of IE does not support the fetch API.

Comment: Then a polyfil is for you. Please have a look to the text above where is the sentence: "...If about the older browsers a polyfill will emulate the missing function..." for the link.

Comment: Note that this answer is not entirely accurate - Requestor is under active development again it seems, with 1.0.0-rc1 published about 2 months ago, Dec 2021.